# switch always default after I input data

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement

Maybe there is no problem in running the first code
However,it will always default after I enter comment's data

```
char answer;

do{
    printf("Do you want to add new comment?Y/N: ");
    scanf("%c",&answer);
    fflush(stdin);

    switch(tolower(answer)) 
    {
        case 'y':
            comment();
            break;

        case 'n':
            main();
            break;

        default:
            printf("Wrong choice !\n\n");
            break;
    }
}while(tolower(answer)!=='y'||'n');
```

there is the code of comment(),I guess the problem at here.

```
FILE*fp=fopen("comment.txt","a+");

if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("FIle not Found");
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    gets(c.name);
    printf("Pleas enter the date: ");
    gets(c.date);
    printf("Please enter the movie name: ");
    gets(c.movie);
    printf("Please enter your comment in 100 words:\n");
    printf("Please press [Tab]and[Enter] to submit your comment\n");
    scanf("%[^\t]",c.comment);

    fprintf(fp,"%s    %s\n%s\n%s\n\n",c.name,c.date,c.movie,c.comment);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Can someone help me?Thx!!

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` - This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry.What am I get the mistake from my post @Yunnosch

Comment: Sorry? I do not get the meaning of your comment.

Answer (score 2):

try using `strlwr()` instead of `tolower()`

Answer (score 2):

Compiler gives you no error for while condition?

Maybe you want to write:

```
while(tolower(answer)!='y'||tolower(answer)!='n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `do{}while` you are reading input buffer which has a character you entered and a enter key. You need to clear that. Try `scanf("%c%*c",&answer);` .which will read that extra character from the buffer

Comment: It still has the problem, THX

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems in your code.

```
scanf("%c",&answer);
```

When you enter a character for the first time and if the character if either `y` or `n` then in next iteration this `scanf()` will read the stray `\n` (newline) character from the input buffer. To overcome this problem, add a space character before `%`, like this:

```
scanf(" %c",&answer);
```

Another problem is this statement:

```
while(tolower(answer)!=='y'||'n'); 
                     ^^    ^
```

The compiler must be giving you both error and warning in this statement.

Change this to:

```
while(tolower(answer)=='y'||tolower(answer)=='n');
```

With this the loop to be run till user give input either `y` or `n` and for any other character, the loop will exit.

If you don't want loop to exit for any input character other then `y` or `n` but just print the message `Wrong choice !` message then you can do:

```
}while(tolower(answer)!='y'||tolower(answer)!='n');
```

Comment: It is work!! The 2nd problem is my careless mistake. Anyway, Thank you~